# How to check a particular cookie and it's value in android mobile browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, cookies

I need to validate the content of a SSO cookie in android mobile browser.

I am able to see cookie file from particular domain (account.xxx.com),but unable to see individual cookie in it.

Is there any way to see cookie content in android?

Comment: I meant ,i can see cookie of 4KB present in my android chrome browser,but can not open it,as no option there,i just want to check a particular cookie and it's value in cookie file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all data (in the same way as in desktop browser) by using remote debugging:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

As normal go to Resources > Cookies

Answer (score 0):

Just connect your mobile to computer and use chrome to debug:

[image]